# vertica executing copy command with default value

Tags: vertica

I'm trying to run copy command that populate the db based on concatenation of the csv, **but one column needs to be hardcoded**.

Table columns names are:

```
col1,col2,col3
```

File content is (just the numbers, names are the db column names):

```
1234,5678,5436
```

What i need is a way to insert data say like this: based on my example:

I want to put in the db:

```
col1  col2  col3
1234  5678  10
```

Notice: **10 as hardcoded, ignoring the real value of col3 at db**

Should I use `FILLER`? if so what is the command?

my starting point is:

```
COPY SAMPLE.MYTABLE (col1,col2,col3) 
FROM LOCAL 'c:\\1\\test.CSV' 
UNCOMPRESSED DELIMITER ',' NULL AS 'NULL' ESCAPE AS '\' RECORD TERMINATOR ' ' ENCLOSED BY '"' DIRECT STREAM NAME 'Identifier_0' EXCEPTIONS 'c:\\1\\test.exceptions' 
REJECTED DATA 'c:\\1\\test.rejections' ABORT ON ERROR NO COMMIT;
```

Can you help how to load those columns (basically col3)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to just use a dummy filler to parse (but ignore) the 3rd value in your csv.  Then you need to use `AS` to do an expression to assign the third table column to a literal.

I've added it to your COPY below. However, I'm not sure I understand your `RECORD TERMINATOR` setting. I'd look at that a little closer. Perhaps you had a copy/paste issue or something.

```
COPY SAMPLE.MYTABLE (col1, col2, dummy FILLER VARCHAR, col3 AS 10) 
FROM LOCAL 'c:\1\test.CSV' UNCOMPRESSED DELIMITER ',' 
NULL AS 'NULL' ESCAPE AS '\' RECORD TERMINATOR ' ' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' DIRECT STREAM NAME 'Identifier_0' 
EXCEPTIONS 'c:\1\test.exceptions' REJECTED DATA 'c:\1\test.rejections' 
ABORT ON ERROR NO COMMIT;
```